# How to properly use both pear and pear2 packages?

Tags: php, pear, pyrus

I've set my pear installation inside my project:

> php pyrus.phar mypear c:\apache24\htdocs\my-project\vendor

But it creates the following folder structure:

```
.configsnapshots
docs
downloads
php <---------- Here is where pyrus is installing pear + pear2 packages
tests
.pear2registry
```

Then, should I just add \my-project\vendor\php to my include_path and just require the clases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEAR packages not only ship PHP code, but also unit tests, documentation and data files (e.g. font files for barcodes or figlets). The directory structure you see is the result of this separation.

So yes, add the `php` dir to your include path and start requiring the files. You may also simply use a [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/0/) compatible autoloader.